# Como manejar texto eficientemente en Scripts cmd windows

Tags: cmd, vbscript

estoy buscando la manera de poder manipular un archivo de texto mediante un script de archivo de lotes (.bat)

Al parecer cmd no tiene mucha potencia para dichas tareas, así que he estado investigando un poco por Internet y he encontrado algunas cosas que no termino de entender.

Al parecer existe un componente en windows que permite ejecutar ciertas ordenes o comandos de otros lenguajes de scripting de la plataforma .NET como VBscript o Javascript desde cmd de windows.

La cuestión en si es que toda la información que he podido recopilar es difusa e incompleta y ando un poco perdido sobre que herramientas debería aprender a usar para lograr manipular ficheros de texto de forma eficiente con cosas que vienen nativamente con windows (no puedo instalar nada ni añadir ningún componente nuevo que no este ya de por si en el sistema).

Expongo los conceptos que he podido encontrar : "WScript Object" , "FileSystemObject" y "COM Objects en Windows Script Host".

Aunque estoy un poco familiarizado, soy relativamente nuevo en los lenguajes orientados a objetos, tan solo he visto un poco de .NET y todabia soy muuy novato en todo esto.

Resumiendo, quisiera saber que herramientas/lenguaje/recursos necesitaría para poder completar mis scripts de cmd, añadiendole posibilidad de leer, escribir, editar archivos de texto plano de forma eficiente.

Un saludo.

Comment: lo mejor es dejar de utilizar cmd y utilizar directamente visual basic. Si haces `echo %PATHEXT%` verás que se encuentra listada la extención `.vbs` esto significa que estos archivos son auto ejecutables, si no eres experto en visual basic podrías utilizar Javascript a través de JScript de windows. Ambas opciones son mejores que cmd y totalmente intercambiables en plataformas windows (en el sentido que no debes instalar nada para ejecutarlos)

Answer (score 1):

Lamentablemente el CMD de Windows no está muy orientado a la programación. Y cosas tan sencillas como lo que necesitas son bastantes complicadas de realizar. Si tu necesidad es aplicar filtros o modificar contenido, puedes usar el port de [SED](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) para Windows.

> Sed (editor de secuencias) no es realmente un verdadero editor de texto o procesador de texto. En su lugar, se usa para filtrar texto, es decir, toma entrada de texto y realiza alguna operación (o conjunto de operaciones) en ella y emite el texto modificado. Sed se usa generalmente para extraer parte de un archivo usando patrones de coincidencia o sustituyendo múltiples ocurrencias de una cadena dentro de un archivo.

Si el tratamiento que necesitas es mas avanzado, te recomiendo que uses un lenguaje de scripting ([VBScript](https://desarrolloweb.com/manuales/tutorial-visual-basic-script-manual.html), [JScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98.aspx)) o algún lenguaje interpretado ([Python](https://www.python.org/)).

Yo personalmente uso Python para cualquier necesidad de scripting avanzada que tenga.

Comment: Gracias por las sugerencias, voy a mirar un poco el tema de VBScript ya que parece que este viene siempre de forma nativa y puede ser usado para crear múltiples scripts de manera rápida si necesidad de compilar nada.